# Custom X-header with Sendmail

Tags: perl, email, unix, smtp, sendmail

I would like to configure **sendmail** to include **two custom X-headers** with values **calculated based on** the full **email content/body**. Is it possible to use **perl script** with sendmail to add such custom headers to **each email message sent**?

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Anything before the double newline which starts the body will be a header. I am not sure why you need to ask. Did you try something and it didn't work?

Comment: Sendmail is used by other applications to send mails and I cannot modify those applications, so I need to add headers with some sendmail add-on...

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding functionality you need to MIMEdefang milter.

http://mimedefang.org/
MIMEDefang is an e-mail filtering tool that works with the Sendmail "Milter" library. MIMEDefang lets you express your filtering policies in Perl rather than C, [...]
MIMEDefang is free software: It's released under the terms of the GNU General Public License. It runs under Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris and most other UNIX or UNIX-like systems.

**OR**

Base your solution on Sendmail::PMilter or Sendail:Milter modules fro CPAN.